# Deep frying without schnitzels sticking to each other

Tags: chicken, deep-frying, batter

How do I avoid the phenomenon of pieces of breaded schnitzel sticking together inside the deep fryer

Comment: How are you putting the food into the fryer?  lowering it in a basket?  dropping them in one by one?  if one by one, are you letting them cook for a little bit before you drop it all the way in?  related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/57491/67

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it's better to say: **Don't put them in the deep fryer:** add some pepper, paprika and butter on top of them and put them in the oven at 175°C (350°F) for 20 minutes.

If you insist on using a deep fryer:

- Ensure you have a fryer large enough so they don't touch one another

OR

- Deep fry them one by one in a small fryer and then microwave them all together for 1 minute at 750W just before serving them.

#### ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

I shallow fry them in a cast iron skillet with canola and do not crowd the pan